# How can I target a `label` element by its 'for' attribute?

Tags: css

On this site: http://socialarts.com/map

I'd like to change this checkbox `community-canvass` to yellow.

How can I change the checkboxes individually?
[image]

I can change the color of all checkboxes with this code:

```
.filter-area .filter-by-type ul.filter-type-list li input:checked+label:before {
    background-color: green;
}
```

I've tried adding `#community-canvass` but it doesn't work:

```
.filter-area .filter-by-type ul.filter-type-list li input:checked+label:before #community-canvass{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Checkbox code:

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" checked="" name="type[]" id="community-canvass" value="community-canvass">
<label for="community-canvass">Community Canvass</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use an attribute selector like:

```css
.filter-area .filter-by-type ul.filter-type-list li input:checked+label[for="community-canvass"]:before {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for the first child:

.filter-area .filter-by-type ul.filter-type-list li:first-child input:checked+label:before {
    background: gray;
}

use this for the last child:

.filter-area .filter-by-type ul.filter-type-list li:last-child input:checked+label:before {
    background: red;
}